# How to roll up text-based columns with a pivot query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access table that has a `UniqueId` and multiple `phone Numbers` per Id.
*Can I roll those phone numbers up into separate columns?* There are 160 thds plus rows with countless phone #'s

All fields are TEXT fields.

```
 ID         Phone
  1           502
  1           402
  2           375
  3           502
  4           777
  4           645
```

Results I would like to see...

```
 ID         Phone1      Phone2     Phone3
  1          502         402       
  2          375
  3          502
  4          777         645
```

Comment: Since it's not clear the strategy you're trying, there are too many possible answers to speculate upon; as many could be beyond your engineering level.  We don't know since you didn't post what you've tried

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how to handle the fact that all of the fields are text fields.  Good Luck!

Comment: This was very helpful and works. I have started to break down the Dcount formula to try and understand the concept.              row_id: "Phone" & DCount("Phone","[WrkingFile]","cLng(IndividualMatchID)=" & CLng([IndividualMatchID]) & " AND cLng(ID)<=" & CLng([ID]))     What exactly are we doing with the Criteria? ([IndividualMatchID]) & " AND cLng(ID)<=" & CLng([ID]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the following steps:

1. Use the DCount function to assign the "Phone1", "Phone2", etc to the field.
2. Use a [Pivot Query](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read--by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8).

To use this approach, you will need to make sure your table has a Unique Identifier in it. (i.e. you can add an "autonumber" field if there isn't already one)

Here is a sample query for Step 1

```
SELECT Table1.UniqueID, Table1.ID, Table1.Phone, 
"Phone" & DCount("Phone","Table1","ID=" & [ID] & " AND UniqueID<=" & [UniqueID]) AS row_id
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.ID, Table1.Phone;
```

Since you later mentioned that all of your fields are text fields, here is a query that uses the "CLng()" command to cast the text into a Long Integer.

```
SELECT WrkingFile.ID
     , WrkingFile.IndividualMatchID
     , WrkingFile.Phone
     , "Phone" & DCount("Phone","[WrkingFile]","cLng(IndividualMatchID)=" & CLng([IndividualMatchID]) & " AND cLng(ID)<=" & CLng([ID])) AS row_id
FROM WrkingFile
ORDER BY WrkingFile.IndividualMatchID, WrkingFile.Phone;
```

This will give you output that looks like this:

[image: data before pivot]

Now in Step 2 the row_id field can be pivoted into columns.  Use the Pivot Table Wizard to assist, or here is sample SQL:

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.[Phone]) AS FirstOfPhone
SELECT Query1.[ID]
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.[ID]
PIVOT Query1.[row_id];
```

Here is the output:

[image: Final pivoted results]

The above was summarized from a [post by Roger Carlson](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/sequential-row-numbering-on-grouped-results-in/c14558b2-3d74-4313-beba-d72ec2cf7682) from the Microsoft Access Community Website.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, This runs but I receive an error under the row_id. Thinking b/c my column in text, could that be the error? See syntax below if you don't mind...                                                                                                                           SELECT [WrkingFile].ID, [Wrking File].IndividualMatchID, [Wrking File].Phone,
"Phone" & DCount("Phone","[WrkingFile]","IndividualMatchID=" & [IndividualMatchID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID]) AS row_id

FROM [Wrking File]
ORDER BY [WrkingFile].[IndividualMatchID], [WrkingFile].[Phone];

Comment: SELECT [WrkingFile].ID, [WrkingFile].IndividualMatchID, [WrkingFile].Phone, "Phone" & DCount("Phone","[WrkingFile]","IndividualMatchID=" & [IndividualMatchID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID]) AS row_id 

FROM [WrkingFile] 

ORDER BY [WrkingFile].[IndividualMatchID], [WrkingFile].[Phone];

Comment: What does the error say?  The code that you included in your second post looks correct:

Comment: The query runs but I get #Error under row_id, I click on the error and the error boxs reads "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" I have text in my phone column, thinking this would be the reason why but I cannot change the data type to test.

Comment: Strange, I copy and paste your code above into my test database, and the query executes without issues.  What datatypes are your other fields?  Make sure that `ID = Long Integer`, and `IndividualMatchID=Long Integer`.  Phone can be Short Text.

Comment: I changed my data types to interger/number and the query works. Thank you for all the help. Still would liek to know how that formula would work with all text for my data...

Comment: Which fields were text fields? If you update your original question with the data type information, I will try to adjust the answer to include a working example.

Comment: Thanks Josh. All fields are text and I have updated my questions.